# upload image and save file stream in View State

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (Upload.Value !="")
    {
        System.IO.Stream fs = Upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        img_uploadStream = Upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = CreateThumbnail(br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length),150);
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        imageField.Src = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", "image/jpeg", base64String);
    }
}
```

After upload the image , Upload.PostedFile.InputStream has set to null value . 
I want to save this Input Stream to asp.net View State to reuse .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
public Byte[] YourImage
{
get
{
if(ViewState["Key"] != null)
{
 return (Byte[]) ViewState["Key"];
}
return null;
}

set
{
  ViewState["Key"] = value;
}
}
```

Comment: i'am happy to help you zey

Answer (score 0):

Set ViewState inside upload_Click:

```
ViewState["ImageStream"]=Upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
```

Then you can get your viewstate anywhere within the page where you want to use:

```
System.IO.Stream fstream=(System.IO.Stream)ViewState["ImageStream"];
```

Comment: I've tried it ! but i got this error( Type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable. )

Comment: whatever , Thanks for your answer , Ken Clark :)